# Do I need to keep APIs code in separate folder then normal controller?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am following the below guideline for creating REST APIs in codeigniter HMVC setup along with existing controllers which are serving html output. 
I am finding this guide very useful and I have followed that.

https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/06/03/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter/

Now one of my team member feels that we don't need the below structure

```
     Application/Modules/

                    Module1/
                      Model/
                      View/
                      Controller/
                                some_controller.php
                                Api/
                                   api.php
```

instead we can directly put api.php in side controller folder on same level as some_controller.php?

I know what he is suggesting is not a best practice. But to make the development more faster do I directly put api.php on same level as some_controller.php?

Comment: "Secondly , REST calls should not be mixed in with your normal controllers. It should be kept separate from your normal controllers as they are not the same. The default behavior should be slightly different as REST calls are not simple GET -> output."


From the above article, This is clear that what I did is right but I want to know more reasons that why technically it need to be done.

Comment: The structure is meant to organize files in a way that makes sense. If the purposed structure does not work for you, make alterations. There is no predefined standard for these kind of things. Find your own (concise) way of structuring a project that works for you.

Comment: It's better to have a file only for your API functions, you don't need to put it in a folder. But your API controller file will extend REST_Controller with a lot of methods you don't need for "normal" controlers, and it's more easy to secure a single URL like /api/function. Since API returns only data, and controllers return views, it's logical to not mix them.

Comment: @VincentDecaux  If I put the file at the same level as normal controller is there any possibility of loosing the nature of Rest Response made by Rest Server?

Comment: Not at all. In a folder, it just adds /api/ to your URL.

Comment: Thanks to ensure , but still we are going the above way. It will add better readability to our code.

Comment: I agree with @VincentDecaux